# Impossible to get the signed_request in Facebook Page Tab, through CodeIgniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I'm trying to display a page I generate through CodeIgniter in a Facebook Page Tab. My tab is displaying the page in the iframe perfectly, but when I try to retrieve the `signed_request` to test if the user likes my page, I get nothing at all.

I tried like in [this tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/) at first, and it works as long as I'm not generating my page through CodeIgniter. And then I found I'm not the only one with this problem, and all the solutions I have found so far doesn't work to me. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424316/facebook-php-sdk-with-codeigniter-not-returning-requestsigned-request), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189783/not-receiving-signed-request-in-facebook-iframe-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534241/why-do-i-get-an-undefined-index-for-signed-request-in-my-facebook-app). None of these solutions has worked (even the one that makes you avoid the use of `$_REQUEST`, that CodeIgniter appears to be clearing).

How can I get the `signed_request` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it by myself.

CodeIgniter was making a redirection because of the language detection, which caused the page to lose the `signed_request`.